# Match first instance of Python regex search

Tags: python, regex

I'm looking to the first instance of a match two square brackets using regular expressions. Currently, I am doing

```
regex = re.compile("(?<=(\[\[)).*(?=\]\])")
r = regex.search(line)
```

which works for lines like

```
[[string]]
```

returns `string`

but when I try it on a separate line:

```
[[string]] ([[string2]], [[string3]])
```

The result is

```
string]] ([[string2]], [[string3
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

**Python `*`, `+`, `?` and `{n,m}` quantifiers are greedy by default**

Patterns quantified with the above quantifiers will match as much as they can by default. In your case, this means the first set of brackets and the last. In Python, you can make any quantifier non-greedy (or "lazy") by adding a `?` after it. In your case, this would translate to `.*?` in the middle part of your expression.

Comment: Minor nitpick.  *regular expressions* are not fundamentally greedy or non-greedy.  The python `re` package provides a greedy, recursive backtracking implementation of regular expressions.  (+1 for right answer, though)