# Regex search up to first instance Python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, search, python-3.5

I *know* that there are a bunch of other similar questions to this, but I have built off other answers with no success.
I've dug [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25825660/regex-match-up-to-first-literal), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5074331/match-first-instance-of-python-regex-search), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44314013/regex-match-everything-up-to-first-period), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21972432/proper-case-up-to-first-instance-of), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10008064/match-regex-up-to-first-space)
but this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34246170/regex-to-match-up-to-first-occurrence-of) is closest to what I'm trying to do, however it's in php and I'm using python3

My goal is to extract a substring from a body text.
The body is formatted:

```
**Header1**   
thing1  
thing2  
thing3  
thing4 

**Header2**  
dsfgs  
sdgsg  
rrrrrr 

**Hello Dolly**  
abider  
abcder  
ffffff

etc.
```

Formatting on SO is tough. But in the actual text, there's no spaces, just newlines for each line.

I want what's under Header2, so currently I have:

```
found = re.search("\*\*Header2\*\*\n[^*]+",body)
        if found:
            list = found.group(0)
            list = list[11:]
            list = list.split('\n')
            print(list)
```

But that's returning "None". Various other regex I've tried also haven't worked, or grabbed too much (all of the remaining headers).
For what it's worth I've also tried:
`\*\*Header2\*\*.+?^\**$`
`\*\*Header2\*\*[^*\s\S]+\*\*` and about 10 other permutations of those.

Comment: `\n` doesn't exist after `**Header**` because there are spaces.

Comment: @ctwheels removing the \n fixed my issue! If you'd like to post that as an answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Brief

Your pattern `\*\*Header2\*\*\n[^*]+` isn't matching because your line `**Header2**` includes trailing spaces before the newline character. Adding `*` should suffice, but I've added other options below as well.

---

### Code

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/yc5B1G/5)

```
\*{2}Header2\*{2} *\n([^*]+)
```

Alternatively, you can also use the following regex (which also allows you to capture lines with `*` in them so long as they don't match the format of your header `^\*{2}[^*]*\*{2}` - it also beautifully removes whitespace from the last element under the header - uses the `im` flags):

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/yc5B1G/7)

```
^\*{2}Header2\*{2} *\n((?:(?!^\*{2}[^*]*\*{2}).)*?)(?=\s*^\*{2}[^*]*\*{2}|\s*\Z)
```

#### Usage

[See code in use here](https://ideone.com/hVjTER)

```
import re

regex = r"\*{2}Header2\*{2}\s*([^*]+)\s*"

test_str = ("**Header1**   \n"
    "thing1  \n"
    "thing2  \n"
    "thing3  \n"
    "thing4 \n\n"
    "**Header2**  \n"
    "dsfgs  \n"
    "sdgsg  \n"
    "rrrrrr \n\n"
    "**Hello Dolly**  \n"
    "abider  \n"
    "abcder  \n"
    "ffffff")

print(re.search(regex, test_str).group(1))
```

---

### Explanation

The pattern is practically identical to the OP's original pattern. I made minor changes to allow it to better perform and also get the result the OP is expecting.

1. `\*\*` changed to `\*{2}`: Very minor adjustment for performance
2. `\n` changed to `*\n`: Takes additional spaces at the end of a line into account before the newline character
3. `([^*]+)`: Captures the contents the OP is expecting into capture group 1

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
^\*\*Header2\*\*.*[\n\r]
(?P<content>(?:.+[\n\r])+)
```

with the `multiline` and `verbose` modifier, see [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/Q5kBDw/2).
Afterwards, just grab what is inside `content` (i.e. using `re.finditer()`).

---

Broken down this says:

```
^\*\*Header2\*\*.*[\n\r]    # match **Header2** at the start of the line 
                            # and newline characters
(?P<content>(?:.+[\n\r])+)  # afterwards match as many non-null lines as possible
```

---

In `Python`:

```
import re
rx = re.compile(r'''
    ^\*\*Header2\*\*.*[\n\r]
    (?P<content>(?:.+[\n\r])+)
    ''', re.MULTILINE | re.VERBOSE)

for match in rx.finditer(your_string_here):
    print(match.group('content'))
```

---

I have the feeling that you even want to allow empty lines between paragraphs. If so, change the expression to

```
^\*\*Header2\*\*.*[\n\r]
(?P<content>[\s\S]+?)
(?=^\*\*)
```

See [**a demo for the latter on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/Q5kBDw/3) as well.

Comment: my code is never entering the for statement on this :/

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
import re
s = """
**Header1**   
thing1  
thing2  
thing3  
thing4 

**Header2**  
dsfgs  
sdgsg  
rrrrrr 

**Hello Dolly**  
abider  
abcder  
ffffff
"""
new_contents = re.findall('(?<=\*\*Header2\*\*)[\n\sa-zA-Z0-9]+', s)
```

Output:

```
['  \ndsfgs  \nsdgsg  \nrrrrrr \n\n']
```

If you want to remove special characters from the output, you can try this:

```
final_data = filter(None, re.split('\s+', re.sub('\n+', '', new_contents[0])))
```

Output:

```
['dsfgs', 'sdgsg', 'rrrrrr']
```

Comment: this returns an empty array for 'new_contents' for me :/

Comment: @Acoustic77 are you reading from a text file? I achieved the results above by creating a multiline string from the input that you posted.